# EditText Focus and Cursor Selection is Inputting to the Wrong Input Field

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have two EditText fields in my android app. When input is invalid in the first field, an alert dialog is triggered and I try to switch focus and the input cursor back to the EditText field (RollId) that was invalid so it can be re-entered.

The focus change and input cursor actually appears to have worked, *but when I start entering input again, it all show up in the wrong editText (Location) field.*

```
final EditText RollId = findViewById(R.id.scan_roll_id);
final EditText Location = findViewById(R.id.scan_location);

RollId.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (validate.ValidateRollId(String.valueOf(RollId.getText()))) {
                // TODO: parse and populate labels
            } else {
                  // Not a valid RollId format
                  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MoveMaterialActivity.this).create();
                  validate.RollIdAlert("The scanned Roll Id has the incorrect format. Please enter manually.", alertDialog);
                  TextKeyListener.clear(RollId.getText());
                  RollId.setSelection(0);
                  Location.clearFocus();
                  RollId.requestFocus();
           }
       }
   }
});
```

I guess I am basically trying to figure out how to block the input from Location EditText field, or switch it to the RollId EditText field. I thought `RollId.setSelection(0)` would achieve this.

**edit:** RollIdAlert())

```
public void RollIdAlert(String message, AlertDialog alert) {
    alert.setTitle("RollId Format Invalid");
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Post the `RollIdAlert()` method

Comment: Edited to include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your validate.RollIdAlert() method to include a 3d parameter: `EditText et`  
In your listener for the closing of the alert dialog, after `dismiss();`, put these lines:

```
          et.requestFocus();
          et.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: I'm glad_______